# Using sed to delete a case insensitive matched line

Tags: sed, case-insensitive

How do I match a case insensitive regex and delete it at the same time

I read that to get case insensitive matches, use the flag "i"

```
sed -e "/pattern/replace/i" filepath
```

and to delete use d

```
sed -e "/pattern/d" filepath
```

I've also read that I could combine multiple flags like 2iw

I'd like to know if sed could combine both i and d
I've tried the following but it didn't work

```
sed -e "/pattern/replace/id" filepath > newfilepath
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

For case-insensitive use `/I` instead of `/i`.

```
sed -e "/pattern/Id" filepath
```

Comment: Caution: that's not portable. See this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412945/case-insensitive-search-replace-with-sed#comment31685516_4412964

Comment: gnu sed understands both `-E` and `-I`: `gsed -E "/pattern/Id" filepath`

Answer (score 1):

you can use (g)awk as well.

```
# print case insensitive
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/pattern/{print}' file

# replace with case insensitive
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}/pattern/{gsub(/pattern/,"replacement")}1' file
```

OR just with the shell(bash)

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nocasematch
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        *pattern* ) echo $line;
    esac
done <"file"
```

Comment: The only thing is... it keeps the lines to be deleted. So: `awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}!/pattern/{print}' file`

Comment: The `shopt` command is bash-specific and unsupported by ksh.

Answer (score 0):

I produced this one-liner because Ansible cannot handle different lv with the same name.  This convert near CSV into perfect JSON.  Possibly, you want to change the `-F` flag to change the field separator.

```
lvs | perl -ane '
   local %tmp,$i=0;
   while($i<@f){
     $tmp{$f[$i]}=$F[$i] if $F[$i];
     $i++
   };
   if(@f){push @ans,\%tmp}
   else{ @f=@F }; 
   END { print to_json(\@ans,{pretty=>1}) }
' -MJSON
```