# Case-insensitive search and replace with sed

Tags: macos, replace, sed, case-insensitive

I'm trying to use SED to extract text from a log file. I can do a search-and-replace without too much trouble:

```
sed 's/foo/bar/' mylog.txt
```

However, I want to make the search case-insensitive. From what I've googled, it looks like appending `i` to the end of the command should work:

```
sed 's/foo/bar/i' mylog.txt
```

However, this gives me an error message:

```
sed: 1: "s/foo/bar/i": bad flag in substitute command: 'i'
```

What's going wrong here, and how do I fix it?

Comment: @Lazer: I did, but it didn't work. It's stumped me enough that I'm posting a plea for help on SO. :-(

Comment: Can you try updating your copy of sed? `I` is a GNU extension which might be not available with your copy of sed.

Comment: I installed gnu sed, and it does work... but it seems that if I need to run a different program entirely, it might as well be perl.

Comment: **EDIT**: I struck through the OS X qualification, as the OP accepted an answer that doesn’t work on OS X. (As another answer indicated, sed on OS X does not support case-insensitive matching, contrary to Apple documentation.)

Comment: @danorton: Thanks for that; in case you derived the sense that the Apple documentation promises something the implementation doesn't deliver from my answer below: `man sed` IS consistent with the implementation - no mention of (and no support in practice) for case-insensitive matching; if you found a piece of documentation claiming otherwise, please let us know.

Comment: @mklement0, yes, sorry, I stand corrected. The Apple documentation does not make any claim of case-insensitive matching for sed.

Comment: FWIW, the GNU versions of the tools whose BSD version comes with OS X are available from various package managers. I have the full suite of text utilities installed via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) with a `g` prefix, so I can use `gsed` or `gdate` when I need a feature not found in the stock version.

Comment: Since the question does make it clear that this is a BSD implementation issue that directly affects macOS, I think it warrants unstriking the qualification. A query for "macOS case-insensitive sed search" led me here, which leads me to believe it's of particular importance. I am going to unstrike, the community shall judge me.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**Update**: Starting with **macOS Big Sur (11.0)**, **`sed` now *does* support the `I` flag for case-insensitive matching**, so the command in the question should now work (BSD `sed` doesn't report its version, but you can go by the date at the bottom of the `man` page, which should be `March 27, 2017` or more recent); a simple example:

```bash
# BSD sed on macOS Big Sur and above (and GNU sed, the default on Linux)
$ sed 's/ö/@/I' <<<'FÖO'
F@O   # `I` matched the uppercase Ö correctly against its lowercase counterpart
```

<sup>Note: `I` (uppercase) is the documented form of the flag, but `i` works as well.</sup>

Similarly, starting with **macOS Big Sur (11.0)** **`awk` now *is* locale-aware** (`awk --version` should report `20200816` or more recent):

```bash
# BSD awk on macOS Big Sur and above (and GNU awk, the default on Linux)
$ awk 'tolower($0)' <<<'FÖO'
föo  # non-ASCII character Ö was properly lowercased
```

---

The following applies to **macOS *up to Catalina* (10.15)**:

To be clear: On macOS, **`sed` - which is the  *BSD* implementation - does NOT support case-insensitive matching** - hard to believe, but true. The [formerly accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412964/45375), which itself shows a *GNU* `sed` command, gained that status because of the `perl`-based solution mentioned in the comments.

To make that **Perl solution** work with **foreign characters** as well, via UTF-8, use something like:

```
perl -C -Mutf8 -pe 's/öœ/oo/i' <<< "FÖŒ" # -> "Foo"
```

- `-C` turns on UTF-8 support for streams and files, assuming the current locale is UTF-8-based.
- `-Mutf8` tells Perl to interpret the *source code* as UTF-8 (in this case, the string passed to `-pe`) - this is the shorter equivalent of the more verbose `-e 'use utf8;'.`<sup>Thanks, [Mark Reed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797049/mark-reed)</sup>

(Note that **using `awk` is not an option either**, as `awk` on macOS (i.e., *BWK awk* and *BSD awk*) appears to be completely unaware of locales altogether - its `tolower()` and `toupper()` functions ignore foreign characters (and `sub()` / `gsub()` don't have case-insensitivity flags to begin with).)

---

A note on the relationship of `sed` and `awk` to the POSIX standard:

BSD `sed` and `awk` limit their functionality *mostly* to what the [POSIX `sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and
[POSIX `awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) specs mandate, whereas their GNU counterparts implement many more extensions.

Comment: To fix locale: http://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2014/01/12/fixing-perl-warning-setting-locale-failed-on-mac-osx/

Answer (score 89):

<sup>*Editor's note*: This solution doesn't work on macOS (out of the box), because it only applies to *GNU* `sed`, whereas macOS comes with *BSD* `sed`.</sup>

Capitalize the 'I'.

```
sed 's/foo/bar/I' file
```

Comment: I saw this also, and tried it... but I still get the same error message.

Comment: BSD sed has a lot of limitations, it seems. I would do this in PERL (i.e., perl -pe 's/foo/bar/i'), if that's the case.

Comment: The default install of OS X Lion gives the error: sed: 1: "s/foo/bar/I": bad flag in substitute command: 'I'

Comment: if the search&replace is supposed to be global on top of case insensitive, would the syntax be sed 's/foo/bar/Ig' file ?

Comment: The `I` suffix is not a portable use of `sed`.  POSIX `sed` uses only [Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (BREs), which are surprisingly limited.  They don't even support the `+` (you have to use `\{1,\}` instead), let alone case insensitive matching.  The only portable way to do it with sed is to check for something like `/[hH][eE][lL][lL][oO]/`, which is often going to be impractical.

Comment: That needs to be `/gI` othewise it will just operate on the first match.

Answer (score 29):

Another work-around for `sed` on Mac OS X is to install `gsed`from MacPorts or HomeBrew and then create the alias `sed='gsed'`.

Comment: gsed "s/a/b/Ig" works, thanks!
Why should a good working answer get a downvote?

Comment: this answer is great. used `brew install gnu-sed` then went to my ~/.bash_profile and added the alias. Thanks @davmat

Comment: Better to do `brew install gnu-sed --with-default-names` - this will override the default `sed`.

Comment: @Mar0ux the `--with-default-names` is now deprecated: [brew.sh](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/why-was-with-default-names-removed/4405) I added the gnu-sed to my PATH, but I believe there are other workarounds now: [SE question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities)

Answer (score 8):

If you are doing pattern matching first, e.g.,

```
/pattern/s/xx/yy/g
```

then you want to put the `I` after the pattern:

```
/pattern/Is/xx/yy/g
```

Example:

```
echo Fred | sed '/fred/Is//willma/g'
```

returns `willma`; without the `I`, it returns the string untouched (`Fred`).

Comment: On MacOs I get:
`sed: 1: "/fred/Is//willma/g": invalid command code I`

Comment: Good tip. Here's how I use it on a complex search: `sed -r '/'"$PATTERN"'/I,${s//'$YELLOW'&'$NO_COLOR'/g;b};$q3'` . It prints the text, and if pattern (case-insensitive) was found, it highlights text in yellow (ansi color). If not found - returns exit code 3.

Answer (score 6):

The [sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.10) addresses the closely related case-insensitive *search*. It points out that a) many versions of sed support a flag for it and b) it's awkward to do in sed, you should rather use awk or Perl.

But to do it in [POSIX sed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), they suggest three options (adapted for substitution here):

1. Convert to uppercase and store original line in hold space; this won't work for substitutions, though, as the original content will be restored before printing, so it's only good for insert or adding lines based on a case-insensitive match.
2. Maybe the possibilities are limited to `FOO`, `Foo` and `foo`. These can be covered by

   ```
    s/FOO/bar/;s/[Ff]oo/bar/
   ```
3. To search for all possible matches, one can use bracket expressions for each character:

   ```
    s/[Ff][Oo][Oo]/bar/
   ```

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html is what you can portably do in sed

Comment: @D.Shawley That's not contradicting anything in the answer, right? Or did you want to add context by linking to the official spec? I can add it to the answer.

Comment: W Nothing contradictory here. I was happy to see someone referencing POSIX and wanted to add a link.  The majority of the answers here were busily bemoaning the "non-standard" macOS implementation of sed which bothered me.

Comment: @D.Shawley Added a link to the spec now :)

Answer (score 3):

Use following to replace all occurrences:

```
sed 's/foo/bar/gI' mylog.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The Mac version of `sed` seems a bit limited. One way to work around this is to use a linux container (via Docker) which has a useable version of `sed`:

```
cat your_file.txt | docker run -i busybox /bin/sed -r 's/[0-9]{4}/****/Ig'
```

Comment: this is a particularly heinous thing to do.  If anyone is even considering this seriously, just install a GNU sed locally.

Comment: Overkill but useful general approach to know!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need, and came up with this:

this command to simply find all the files:

```
grep -i -l -r foo ./*
```

this one to exclude this_shell.sh (in case you put the command in a script called *this_shell.sh*), tee the output to the console to see what happened, and then use sed on each file name found to replace the text foo with bar:

```
grep -i -l -r --exclude "this_shell.sh" foo ./* | tee  /dev/fd/2 | while read -r x; do sed -b -i 's/foo/bar/gi' "$x"; done
```

I chose this method, as I didn't like having all the timestamps changed for files not modified. feeding the grep result allows only the files with target text to be looked at (thus likely may improve performance / speed as well)

be sure to backup your files & test before using. May not work in some environments for files with embedded spaces. (?)

Answer (score 0):

Following should be fine:

```
  sed -i 's/foo/bar/gi' mylog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but in some contexts its okay to pipe the whole thing through   `tr A-Z a-z`   to lowercase the entire stream.

Sure, you lose the uppercase letters, but that loss may be offset by simplifying other parts of the pipeline.  Numbers and date/time are unaffected too, and the output stream is going to compress better as well.  Email addresses are not case-sensitive, so that doesn't matter.

One downside is case-sensitive identifiers might become awkward.   Sendmail logs would be less use this way.