# Does Solaris 5.10 support sed case-insensitive matching?

Tags: unix, sed

When I try to do a S&R that is case insensitive using an I option at the end of the pattern `s/find-word/replace-word/Ig`, I get an error that the command is garbled.  The exact same works if I run it without the I, i.e. `s/find-word/replace-word/g`.  I am using Solaris 5.10, is it possible that our sed is old and does not support I?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412945/case-insensitive-search-replace-with-sed

Comment: **EDIT:** Not a duplicate, just a poor title for the actual question asked, so I have changed the title, accordingly. The top answer seems to correctly answer the question, but the OP seems to have abandoned the question.

Answer (score 9):

<del>I suggest using a lowercase i:
s/from/to/gi</del>

---

EDIT: Okay, me and my smartassery... According to http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/202109-sed-i-not-available-solaris-5-10-a.html and a lot of other links, seems like sed tool on solaris systems doesn't support the -i option... Best solution then would be to either use a busybox, rebuild GNU sed for your system, or use a perl script to do the work.

Comment: I was using a capital I because an example I had found instructed so.  Tried lowercase as well but to no avail

Answer (score 3):

If your version of `sed` doesn't support the `ignorecase` flag, you might pre-lowercase all input with `tr`:

```
<infile tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sed ...
```

Comment: sed, awk and tr are the most difficult things to deal with on solaris when  writing portable scripts; tr in this case doesn't necessarily help matters (formatting is a little hard in a comment, but I'll try): `$ type -ap tr` on my solaris 5.10 produces: ( `/bin/tr /usr/bin/tr /usr/ucb/tr /usr/xpg4/bin/tr /usr/xpg6/bin/tr` ), so beware : `$ for tr in $( type  -ap tr ); do   echo "$( echo AaBbCc | $tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' ) == $tr ..."; done` yields: 
`aaBbCc == /bin/tr ...
aaBbCc == /usr/bin/tr ...
aabbcc == /usr/ucb/tr ...
AaBbCc == /usr/xpg4/bin/tr ...
AaBbCc == /usr/xpg6/bin/tr ...`

Comment: fyi, as long as not using `/usr/ucb/tr`, this works on the other `tr`'s: `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`. Unfortunately, for portable scripts (even across different solaris boxes, with a different `PATH`), a script needs to test for which `tr` is being used, if you in fact need to use `tr`. (It's almost not worth it.)