# How to use flag with 'sed' on mac?

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I dont find the way to use flag with `sed` and matching pattern.

I'm trying to us the i flag. But I don't understand how it works.

```
$ sed -i '' -n '/xxx.xxx@xxx.fr/i d' res.txt
sed: 1: "/xxx.xxx@xxx.fr/i d": command i expects \ followed by text
```

So I want to match xxx.xxx@xxx.fr And XXX.XXX@XXX.FR

The `-i ''` is only for `--in-file (without cache)` the `d` is for delete.

So how can I use flag and eventually multiple of them ? In the documentation I've found it was that way but it seems not to work at all.

Comment: what are you trying to do, replace xxx.xxx@xxx.fr with something in file res.txt?

Comment: using the -i flag will allow the file to be modified in place, rather than outputting to stdout.

Comment: GNU sed has `I` flag for [case insensitive match](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3120/address-and-address-range/13753/lines-matching-regular-expression-pattern#t=201610260907523706883).. nor sure on OSX..

Comment: @Sundeep nup, tried it already.

Comment: the error you get is probably because sed thinks you want to use the `i` command which inserts something before the matched pattern.. GNU sed will accept this `seq 5 | sed '/3/i d'` but OSX needs ``\`` after `i`.. so `seq 5 | sed '/3/i\ d'`

Comment: MacOS doesn't support case insensitive matching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412945/case-insensitive-search-replace-with-sed

Comment: also, I think you shouldn't be using `-n` option when you need `d` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Perl` - its regexes and options are far more orthogonal and consistent than all the `sed` versions across platforms:

```
perl -i -ne '/XXX.XXX.fr/i || print' res.txt
```

- -i means *"in-place"* editing
- -n means execute a loop around input lines like `awk` or `sed`
- -e means execute following script

Comment: Ok, I'll go with that. Thank you !