# Tricky scanner to get string commands in a text file or Textarea input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, frontend

I have either a text file or Textarea input which needs to be scanned for commands which need a required format.
The commands must be in the following order and aren't string sensitive however integers must be of length 1.

```
1) START 2,4,GO
2) Like
3) ATE, SWAM, SING, DANCE
```

Note,the 3rd command has to be one of those 4 words.
What's the best way to do this?  Should I make an array and then use regexp?

An example:

```
Random text 
ignore this
StArt 2,4,Go
Like
aTE
WORKed
NewCommand again 
StarT 9,1,Go
Like
Swam
```

Hence, this file has 2 commands.  Based on the commands I will do an action.  Output is void.  i.e.) a method like regexp might be used and then when a command is read it will call a method which will map the methods like `function Ate(e) {console.log("ATE")}`

Comment: You have shown the sample input. Can you please show the corresponding sample output? Do you just want that non-command lines are removed? Do you want the three lines of each command to be joined on one line? Or what?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I just need to trigger an action once those series of commands are met and then parse those commands into a function and then ill do an action depending on what was typed in command 1 and 3

Comment: My total lack of JS does not allow me to help you further on this, but someone else will certainly be up to it.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I need it done using a file too so if you can do this in like a .csv or txt file I'd be happy :)

Comment: Then my answer shows how to "filter" `yourfile` using `sed`. The output of that `sed` command is `yourfile` deprived of the lines which are not commands. However, seriously, given my zero knowledge of JS I cannot even guess if my answer makes any sense for your application.

Answer (score 0):

The following `sed` program only prints the relevant lines:

```
sed -n '/^start [0-9],[0-9],go$/I{N;N;/\nlike\n\(ate\|swam\|sing\|dance\)/Ip}' yourfile
```

Note that the `I` flag at the end of the address `/…/` (or of the `s/…/…/` command) is not portable, as explained in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412964/5825294). If you need portability, you have to change `like` to `[lL][iI][kK][eE]` and so on.