# Use sed with ignore case while adding text before some pattern

Tags: linux, unix, sed

```
sed -i '/first/i This line to be added'
```

In this case,how to ignore case while searching for pattern =first

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
sed 's/[Ff][Ii][Rr][Ss][Tt]/last/g' file
```

Otherwise, you have the `/I` and n`/i` flags:

```
sed 's/first/last/Ig' file
```

From man [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html):

> **I**
>
> **i**
>
> The I modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU extension which
>   makes sed match regexp in a case-insensitive manner.

#### Test

```
$ cat file
first
FiRst
FIRST
fir3st
$ sed 's/[Ff][Ii][Rr][Ss][Tt]/last/g' file
last
last
last
fir3st
$ sed 's/first/last/Ig' file
last
last
last
fir3st
```

Comment: You're right!!! But I am searching for any other option Like in grep command ,we have -i option to ignore -case

Comment: I found something in http://stackoverflow.com/q/2157288/1983854 . Check my updated answer.

Comment: the `/i /I` is for gnu sed, and only for `s/../../ (substitution operation)` if I remembered correctly. doesn't work for `/.../p` for example

Comment: Yes Kent,You are right./I and /i This works only for substitution operation

Comment: Yes I see @Kent. I tried for this case http://stackoverflow.com/q/16836306/1983854 and does not work.

Comment: @fedorqui I was wrong. `/.../Ip` worked too. ... should test then post comment... but again, for gnu sed. +1 your answer.

Comment: @Kent It's `/.../I p`; pretty sure you need a space after the modifiers.  It works for all regexes, not just substitution.

Answer (score 9):

#### GNU sed

```
sed '/first/Ii This line to be added' file
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try

```
sed 's/first/somethingelse/gI'
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to save some typing, try awk. I don't think sed has that option

```
 awk -v IGNORECASE="1" '/first/{your logic}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

For versions of awk that don't understand the `IGNORECASE` special variable, you can use something like this:

```
awk 'toupper($0) ~ /PATTERN/ { print "string to insert" } 1' file
```

Convert each line to uppercase before testing whether it matches the pattern and if it does, print the string. `1` is the shortest *true* condition, so awk does the default thing: `{ print }`.

To use a variable, you could go with this:

```
awk -v var="$foo" 'BEGIN { pattern = toupper(foo) } toupper($0) ~ pattern { print "string to insert" } 1' file
```

This passes the shell variable `$foo` and transforms it to uppercase before the file is processed.

Slightly shorter with bash would be to use `-v pattern="${foo^^}"` and skip the `BEGIN` block.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following, \b for word boundary

```
sed 's/\bfirst\b/This line to be added/Ig' file
```